# postgresql Importing csv integer error but the id number is in the file

Tags: postgresql, csv

Hi I did this command on my original DB :

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM cms_title WHERE title = 'Migration-test') TO '/Users/JayCee/cms_title_dump.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' NULL AS '';
```

It worked fine.

But when I try to copy it to an other DB I have this :

```
\COPY cms_title FROM 'cms_title_dump.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "id"
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY cms_title, line 1, column id: "id"

I don't understand, here is what I have when I do a cat -e on my file :

```
id;language;title;page_title;menu_title;meta_description;slug;path;has_url_overwrite;redirect;creation_date;published;publisher_is_draft;publisher_state;page_id;publisher_public_id$
217;en;Migration-test;"";"";"";migration-test;migration-test;f;"";2015-11-24 13:01:52.184969+00;t;t;0;99;218$
```

wow I am so lost even after reading tons of subject.. But contrary to those, I don't see any mistake here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\COPY` command generates a header line which is being read by the import command as data.

Either you do not generate the header line or tell the import command to not read the first line.

To avoid the header line generation omit the `HEADER` option.

To ignore the header line insert the `HEADER` option in the import command.